# Intel 8087 floating point numbers

Tags: assembly, floating-point, precision, intel, x87

Good morning,
I have to change the constant values "wired to code" for an old machine based on intel 8086 and intel 8087 coprocessor.
I have the source code, written in the RTL/2 language. Unfortunately, I have no way to compile the source code. The executable code was loaded onto EPROM. So, I have this old folder which cointains the RTL/2 source files, the object files and the resulting files that look like the EPROM images (files which i assume shall be put in the EPROM).

My idea is to change the real constants directly on the file which shall be put to the EPROM. So, given the real number i see in the source code, e.g. 1.2345  I would like to find its binary\hex representation in order to search for it in the EPROM image and replace it with my new real number.

Reading wikipedia The 8087 did not implement the eventual IEEE 754 standard in all its details. So I wonder: what conversion formula should I use to find the representation of the 32-bit real numbers (I assume) for 8087? Is there any tool\program\code that does this conversion?

I tried to use online converters that given one real number as input provide the hex float representation of the number. But, unfortunately, I can't find these hex strings in my EPROM file.

update: I confirm he processors used are i8086 + coprocessor i8087. In a document i explicitly read that are used floating point number operations.
Unfortunately i do not know if 32/64/80 bit floats are used.
I don't know how many bits are used for a "REAL" variable in RTL/2 Programming language.

update2:
I wrote this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define realNum 0.0010726023 /* One of the real number I hope to find in the EPROM image*/

int main (void)
{

float f = realNum;
double d = realNum;
long double ld = realNum;

unsigned char pnt[20];
int i = 0;
while ( i < 20 )
{
    pnt[i] = 0;
    i++;
}

// float
memcpy( pnt, &f, sizeof(float));
i = 0;
printf("float:");
while ( i < sizeof(float) )
{
    printf("%x",pnt[i]);
    i++;
}
printf("\n");

// double
i = 0;
while ( i < 20 )
{
pnt[i] = 0;
i++;
}

memcpy( pnt, &d, sizeof(double));
i = 0;
printf("double:");
while ( i < sizeof(double) )
{
    printf("%x",pnt[i]);
    i++;
}
printf("\n");


// long double
i = 0;
while ( i < 20 )
{
pnt[i] = 0;
i++;
}

memcpy( pnt, &ld, sizeof(long double));
i = 0;
printf("long double:");
while ( i < sizeof(long double) )
{
    printf("%x",pnt[i]);
    i++;
}
printf("\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In order to see if the hex in the output are in the EPROM file.. unfortunately i cannot find any of the following on the EPROM.

```
float:90968c3a
double:f31235f3d192513f
long double:09897a8998f968cf53f000000
```

For info, I cannot upload anywhere the EPROM file content; but i can paste here some lines ( The only purpose of these copy-paste is to give you an idea\context about "EPROM file" I told you about):

```
...
 :1009600004DF3406028EBB00E3C38B34002607B9D4
 :1009700080C1260602EC8B360702C7024736078382
 :1009800004DE9B568304DCC7003647FF9BD99BC41B
 :100990009BC9DE53DC363F5876C7347F538304DC73
 :1009A000C7003647FF9BD99BC49B5E53DC363F583C
 :1009B00076C7348023D904EC8B360700C7023F3654
 :1009C00007DE8304DF3406028EBB00E3C38B3400F2
 :1009D00026078304DCC74C36475C9BD99BC4B9808F
...
```

thanks in advance for any kind of help

Comment: The 8087 uses standard IEEE 754 numbers for 32 and 64 bit floats.  In fact, IEEE 754 was modelled after the 8087.  Only the 80 bit format is proprietary.  Make sure to also account for field order and byte order when converting.  These differ between architectures with the x86 and MIPS format being the two popular ones.

Comment: Even if the system includes an 8087 math coprocessor, it is possible that a fixed-point representation of some sort was used at the point this data was actually used (e.g. machine control, seeing that RTL/2 was an RTOS). Consider adding more information about the system being used here.

Comment: As fuz mentioned 8087 supports 3 precision formats (32, 64, 80). You have to be sure which format is used. The default is 80-bit BTW.

Comment: @xiver77: There is no default format.  There are different opcodes for each of the 3 sizes for load/store; code always has to pick one.   The *internal* (register) format is fixed at 80-bit, and probably you're thinking of the precision-control bits that allow rounding the mantissa after every operation to 53 or 24 bits; the default is full 80-bit (64-bit mantissa).  But always still with the full exponent range of the 80-bit format; the precision control field on the [control word](http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap1.htm#cword) doesn't override that or prevent load/store in any fmt.

Comment: Note that `float f = realNum; long double ld = realNum;` is taking a `double` constant and initializing a non-`double`.  Better to use `0.0010726023f` and `0.0010726023L` - note suffix.  This may affect the patterns in which you seek.